# MOOC Java: Advanced Astrology, issue with right leaning triangle

Tags: java

So I'm doing the MOOC course on Java and have been stuck on the same problem for days. I have everything else down, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the triangle right. The first part is printing a right-leaning triangle based on the input size. Here is my code:

```
 
public class AdvancedAstrology {

    public static void printStars(int number) {
        // part 1 of the exercise
        int i = 0;
        while (i < number){
            System.out.print("*");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void printSpaces(int number){
        // part 1 of the exercise
        int i = 0;
        while (i < number){
            System.out.print(" ");
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void printTriangle(int size) {
        // part 2 of the exercise
        int i = 0;
        int j = size;
        if(size == 1){
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println("");
        }else{
            while (i <= size){
                printSpaces(j);
                printStars(i);
                j--;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void christmasTree(int height){
        // part 3 of the exercise
        int i = 1;
        int j = height - 1;
        
        while (i <= height){
            printSpaces(j);
            printStars(i*2-1);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        printSpaces(height-2);
        printStars(3);
        printSpaces(height-2);
        printStars(3);
        
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The tests are not checking the main, so you can modify it freely.
        
        printTriangle(3);
        System.out.println("---");
        christmasTree(4);
        System.out.println("---");
        christmasTree(10);
    }
}
```

and output:

```
   
  *
 **
***
---
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
  ***
  ***
---
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
        ***
        ***
```

The trees I have figured out, but the issue is the empty space above the right-leaning triangle will not let me pass the test. Here is the error I get:

```
ComparisonFailure: You printed incorrectly when printTriangle(3) was  called. expected:<  []*
 **
***
> but was:<  [ 
  ]*
 **
***
>
```

Edit: I've implemented your edit but now have the issue of the output being this:

```
   *
  **
 ***
---
```

The triangle has a space in front of each line

Edit: Thanks guys for the quick responses! All the tests have been passed

Answer (score 1):

You can add these lines of code in your printTriangle method:

```
if (i != 0) {
    printSpaces(j);
    printStars(i);
}
```

so it becomes:

```
public static void printTriangle(int size) {
    // part 2 of the exercise
    int i = 0;
    int j = size;
    if (size == 1) {
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println("");
    } else {
        while (i <= size) {
            if (i != 0) {
                printSpaces(j);
                printStars(i);
            }
            j--;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

or

---

better solution is just changing the initial value of i and j:

```
int i = 1;
int j = size - 1;
```

so the final version is:

```
public static void printTriangle(int size) {
    // part 2 of the exercise
    int i = 1;
    int j = size - 1;
    if (size == 1) {
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println("");
    } else {
        while (i <= size) {
            printSpaces(j);
            printStars(i);
            j--;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I don't think I would have thought of this but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your `printTriangle` method starts at i = 0, meaning your first line prints 0 stars. Set it to i = 1.

```
    public static void printTriangle(int size) {
        // part 2 of the exercise
        int i = 1; //<-- This line changed
        int j = size - 1; //<-- This line is also changed
        if(size == 1){
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println("");
        }else{
            while (i <= size){
                printSpaces(j);
                printStars(i);
                j--;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment, This issue was resolved simply but is now causing a different issue. The space at the top has now moved to the side of the triangle. The output for just the triangle has changed to this: 
`
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
---
`

Ill post edit

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?

```
printTriangle(4);
```

prints

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

The method.

```
public static void printTriangle(int size) {
    // part 2 of the exercise
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(size-i) + "*".repeat(i));
    }
}
```